# cant override styles in modal component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the modal component in material ui and I am having trouble overriding the auto display styles they have for the component.

Here is my use styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    inset: '1px 1px 0 0',
    width: '40vw',
   
  },
})
```

```
<Modal
    aria-labelledby='transition-modal-title'
    aria-describedby='transition-modal-description'
    className={classes.modal}
>
```

the default css properties are overriding the styles I wrote in classes.modal, why is this happening and how can I fix it? I need to change the inset property completely

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear styles if you can't override it with a class.

`<Modal style={{inset:'1px 1px 0 0',width:'40vw'}}>`

Answer (score 0):

try to use (paper and <Fade/>):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  modal: {
    inset: "1px 1px 0 0",
    width: "40vw"
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: "2px solid gray",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3)
  }
}));
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-styled-9ctwi?file=/src/App.js:221-495)